# Android Application will not connect to server

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

My android application used to be able to connect to the Facebook server via the API, but now it won't for some reason. I keep on getting this message in my log cat

D/Facebook-authorize(417): Login failed: com.facebook.android.DialogError: The connection to the server was unsuccessful.

Ive read many stack overflow questions regarding this, without answer. I am hoping someone can help me with this. Thank you!

Here is some of my code with my App ID edited out

```
public class BreadcrumbsActivity extends Activity {

static Facebook facebook = new Facebook("*************");
String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
static SharedPreferences mPrefs;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    /*
     * Get existing access_token if any
     */
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if(access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }
    if(expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);           
    }

    /*
     * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
     */
    if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"user_likes", "user_photos", "email", "offline_access", "publish_actions"}, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Login Succesful.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(BreadcrumbsActivity.this, MainMenu.class);                   
                BreadcrumbsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Login Failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(BreadcrumbsActivity.this, MainMenu.class);                   
                BreadcrumbsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Comment: unfortunately, the app is mysteriously connecting now...i should have exported the log cat when it happened so i could fix the problem permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error- 417  Expectation Failed**

> The 417 status code means that the server was unable to properly
>   complete the request. One of the headers sent to the server, the
>   "Expect" header, indicated an expectation the server could not meet.